# Projecting from Bessel 1841 to WGS 1984

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, coordinate-system

I am having problem with projecting my counties which are in GSC_1841/Hermannskoegel to WGS_1984 in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3. I tried the basic "project" with importing the existing coordinate system but that's pretty much it and nothing happens. Somebody advised me that first I have to change the ellipsoid manually, and then do the transformation using predefined seven values/numbers.

Could anyone be more specific?

Old Yugoslavia is the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Full transformation info

```
ΔX(m)  682
ΔY(m) -203
ΔZ(m)  480
```

---

#### Full Ellipsoid info

Bessel ellipsoid 1841 (defined by log a and ƒ):

```
a = 6,377,397.155 m
ƒ = 1 / 299.1528153513233 (0.003342 773154 ± 0.000005)
b = 6,356,078.963 m.
```

Earth ellipsoid WGS84 (defined directly by a and ƒ):

```
a = 6,378,137.0 m
ƒ = 1 / 298.257223563
b = 6,356,752.30 m.
```

---

In ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 the transformation code for some reason is **108264**.